# CSS: Merging Div and Table Borders

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

[image: Desired Result]

I want to achieve was is shown on the picture above. I have a div with a table inside of it, and I want their borders to merge. So far I've had partial success with the CSS on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uQFLX/

As you can see, the right side is wrong. I can fix this by setting the width of the table manually, but I need its size to be dynamic. Is there a way to achieve this while keeping the width: 100% property on the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to merge the borders, get rid of the left/right borders on the table instead.

You could change your style to this:

```
table
{
   margin: 0;
   width: 100%;
   border-top: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}
```

Updated your fiddle to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/uQFLX/1/

Comment: I'll have to do the same for the th's on the left and right edges of the table, but at this point I think I can figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @JayPea Great, let me know if you run in to any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the width of the table to 402px, not 100%

```
   width: 402px;
```

Comment: The OP stated that he wants to keep the table size dynamic.